# How can I accurately measure the thrust of AR Drone 2.0 motors/props?

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to find a precise function for thrust to PWM of the AR drone 2.0. I have control of the drone with my computer so PWM is not an issue.
Has this been done before/ what might be a good approach to finding this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274259/how-can-i-accurately-measure-the-thrust-of-ar-drone-2.0-motors/props?/) by [afurth7](https://answers.ros.org/users/32318/afurth7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tie/strap/tape the drone on a set of electronic scales (electronic ones would be the best) and then rev the motors in whatever configuration you would be interested in. I would suggest taring the weight of the drone with the motors off, (if your scale measures negative values) and get the direct measurement of thrust on the scale.

You can then plot these values against pwm on the motors, regress to find an appropriate model using any number of regression techniques.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
Thanks for your answer @PeterMilani, but tbh this is not a ROS question.

@afurth7: with over 36000 questions we try to stay on topic as much as possible here on ROS Answers, and although you can use the AR drone *with* ROS, system identification is too generic a topic to cover here on ROS Answers.